# Delphi: old QuickReport element size as autostretched or aligntobottom?

Tags: delphi, label, cell, shapes, quickreports

We have old QuickReport with Delphi 6 Professional.

We uses QRShape to make "table" (as in html, or Excel), not the frame (because the frame size is commonly different than shape, and in QRLabel/QRDBText we don't have spacing option...

So QRShape used as Rectangles (Cells) and Lines.

The main problem that when I have a Memo Field with AutoStretch option then I cannot set the Height of the Shape.

In these cases it would be good if I can set the shape to AutoStretched, or Aligned...
Have the QR some mechanism to set the Shape height as the parent Band's height dynamically?

Thanks for your help!

Regards: dd

Answer (score 1):

The QuickReport suppor said:

> Hi,   we have added these features to the later versions of
>   QuickReport. I can't think of any way to do it with old QR.   Regards,
>   Lut Mentz

Such a life... :-)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still interested in the solution to this, the component QRFrameLine does the job to change to the height of band